# How to serve one instance of an Angular app for each random route (like in meet.jit.si)

Tags: angular, websocket, real-time

This question is somehow hard to ask and may be subject to change. How is it possible to have an Angular app that loads an instance of itself on every route/url? For example: If you go to `http://happy-app.com/happy` it has its own state. And if you then go to `http://happy-app.com/happier` you have the same app, but in another state. As reference look at [meet.jit.si](https://meet.jit.si). Later there would be a real time collaboration between users on the same url.

So, what technologies would you suggest I use? Is this possible with angular alone (disregard the real time collaboration)? Or is that a server side e.g. tomcat configuration? I'm also open for other frameworks (if they have a good ecosystem).

Answer (score 0):

Your URL would look like this:

```
http://happy-app.com/:meetingId
```

meetingId is a variable in your URL. It is called [route parameters](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters).